# How do I show only current selected image and hide it if not select?

Tags: jquery

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/6GdW6/

```
$(".thumbnail").live("click", function() {
    $(".fullimage").hide();
    var i = $("<img />").attr("src", this.href).load(function() {
        $(".fullimage").attr("src", i.attr("src")).addClass("selected");
        $(".fullimage").fadeIn();
    });
    return false;
});
```

1. How to show first image by default if no click?
2. How to add `selected` class only on active link?

I want to keep current `html` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".thumbnail").on("click", function() {
    var selector = '.fullimage[src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]';

    $(".fullimage").hide();

    $(selector).fadeIn();
    return false;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6GdW6/2/

Comment: it's possible to make the big image click able and go to the next image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349913/how-do-i-make-image-click-able-and-go-to-the-next-image

Answer (score 2):

I've update the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6GdW6/5/
It works like a charm, I hope...

Why using 3  tags, I guess only one is necessary :

```
<div id="fullimage">
 <img class="fullimage selected" src="http://i.imgur.com/W2SkQ.gif" alt=""  /> 
</div>
```

// Css

```
#fullimage .selected {display:block;}​
```

// Something like that for js

```
$(".thumbnail").live("click", function() {
    $(".fullimage").fadeOut();
    var i = $("<img />").attr("src", this.href).load(function() {
        $(".fullimage").attr("src", i.attr("src")).addClass("selected");
        $(".fullimage").fadeIn();
    });
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @Valky.. Let's say I disable javascript and I'll see only one image.