# How do I make image click able and go to the next image?

Tags: jquery

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/x5mCR/

With the current code how do I make the big image click able and it will go to next image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#fullimage img').on('click', function() {
    $(".fullimage").hide();
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length > 0) {
        next.fadeIn();    
    } else {
        $('#fullimage img:first').fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x5mCR/6/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fullimage').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var next_img = $(this).next('img');
    if (!next_img.length) {
        next_img = $('#fullimage img.fullimage:first-child').fadeIn();
    }

    $(this).fadeOut(function() {
        next_img.fadeIn();  
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5mCR/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add click action to each fullimage class.
$('.fullimage').click(function() {
    // If there is a next image, hide the current, show the next.
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).toggle();
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x5mCR/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fullimage").on('click', function() {
    $(".fullimage").hide();
    if (!$(this).next().fadeIn().length) // if there's no next image..
        $(".fullimage:first").fadeIn();  // fadein the first one
});
```

Comment: PS. whenever you hide the images, you should also `.css('opacity', 1)`. Otherwise if an image is hidden halfway, next time it will `fadeIn` only halfway too.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the end and it works fine:

```
$(".fullimage").click(function(){       
    $(this).hide().next().show();           
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5mCR/7/