# How to make image always go to next one

Tags: javascript, html, css

so this may look like [How do I make image click able and go to the next image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349913/how-do-i-make-image-click-able-and-go-to-the-next-image)
but it is  the same and different, I am making sort of a comic thing for myself, and their is about 83 imgs and input/img tags, what i want is sort of , an onclick thing where when you click the img it will go to the next, but you can manually scroll if u want, so instead of writing in each one a different id or class to go to, i wanted to see what a javascript function or jquery could do cause im not that good in those languages, any help is appreciated!
heres what each img looks like

```
<input  type="image" src="32c454ebb802ac7b6f93120d8955c7c0_html_140f0bfc048ed85.jpg" name="Image1" align="center" border="0"/>
```

and the css for it

```
input {
height: 100vh;
margin-left: 50vh;}
```

if you need any more of the code just ask :) thanks

Comment: it may sound like a bad question, im not sure if i did the best asking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function scrollNext(el) {
  var bounding = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  window.scroll({
    top: window.scrollY + bounding.top + bounding.height,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
input {
height: 100vh;
margin-left: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="scrollNext(this)"  type="image" src="32c454ebb802ac7b6f93120d8955c7c0_html_140f0bfc048ed85.jpg" name="Image1" align="center" border="0"/>
<input onclick="scrollNext(this)" type="image" src="32c454ebb802ac7b6f93120d8955c7c0_html_140f0bfc048ed85.jpg" name="Image1" align="center" border="0"/>
<input onclick="scrollNext(this)" type="image" src="32c454ebb802ac7b6f93120d8955c7c0_html_140f0bfc048ed85.jpg" name="Image1" align="center" border="0"/>
```